# Подсказки для параметров класса. C# VS2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Допустим, есть класс:

```
class Experimental
{
    public string a { get; set; }  // Параметр двигателя
    public long A { get; set; }    // Параметр поршня...
    public string s { get; set; }  //....
    public long S { get; set; }
    public decimal p { get; set; }
    public decimal P { get; set; }
    public long b { get; set; }
    public long B { get; set; }
    public long T { get; set; }
    public string t { get; set; }
    public string g { get; set; }
}
```

Члены класса имеют названия так себе. Описания в комментарии. Как сделать так, чтобы при использовании класса выводилась подсказка, которая в комментарии. Есть такое в VS?
[image: Подсказка]

Comment: Напишите 3 слеша (`///`) и вам студия сгенерирует шаблон комментария документации, который и будет отображаться.

Comment: это называется [XML комментарии](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc)

Comment: То, что вы хотите написать документацию своему коду - это хорошо. Но будет ещё лучше, если вы переименуете свойства и дадите им нормальные говорящие имена.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov  угу, особенно, если это требование заказчика и формат определён третьей стороной

Comment: Требование заказчика к чему именно? К коду или формату передачи данных? Но это жесть конечно, а не требование, в любом случае.